# "Required request body is missing" when changing from RequestParam to RequestBody

Tags: spring

I followed the [Accessing Data with MySQL](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) official Spring Tutorial as a starting point.

I then changed the `addNewUser` method's `@GetMapping` into a `@PostMapping`, and changed the `@RequestParam` (header) arguments of that same method into `@RequestBody` arguments like so:

```
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email) {
```

into

```
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestBody String name, @RequestBody String email) {
```

since I expected that would move each argument from the header into the request body.

I sent a POST to the same URL, with a JSON (application/json) with the required fields using Postman, and the returned error is `"Required request body is missing"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the correct usage of `@RequestBody` annotation is to reference a Java POJO that contains each of the JSON attributes, in this case a `User` class that contains `name` and `email`. Using `@RequestBody` for each attibute is incorrect.

As soon as I changed

```
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestBody String name, @RequestBody String email) { ...
```

into

```
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestBody User user) { ...
```

the endpoint worked as expected.

([It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))